# A- and MX-record

Tags: dns, mx-record

I wish to point my domain to a web-server and a mail server.

I have pointed the domain A record to the IP. As I understand this will make references to the webserver (browsers) and also SSH work?

I now wish to make DNS references for the mail server.
Is it enough to point an MX-record to `mail.mydomain.com`?

Here is a [screenshot](http://img839.imageshack.us/img839/1348/52547080.jpg) from my account at my name registrar. The name registrar (named loopia) already has some forwarding of the email to the domain. There is also a reference to a domain `XXXX.tw`; I think that must be an old misprint of mine.

Can I just erase all of this and only keep the A-record reference for web-server and SSH (also keep NS records, of course)? After that I just add a MX-pointer (under the heading "@") to `mail.mydomain.com` for the mail server to be referenced properly?

So in the screen shot I only keep the NS records and the A record under www??

When I enter MX-pointers I need to supply information regarding:

1. TTL – What is a suitable TTL time?
2. "Data" – Do I need to put anything under "Data"?

EDIT:
I have now edited my account at the registrar. It now looks like [this](http://img152.imageshack.us/img152/4645/loopia.jpg). Is this OK?
(The servers can not be installed today for testing, but I wish to have the DNS settings correct.)

(I entered `mail.mydomain.com` as data, but it shows up as only "mail" in the overview)

Answer (score 2):

To get mail working, you need two things:

1) an MX record pointing to the host you want mail delivered to (in your example "mail" is just fine)

2) An A record for the host you're pointing to.  IE, you need an A record for the IP address for "mail", which you're missing at the moment.

As for the TTL, it really is just the longest period of time you want someone to notice when you make changes.  If you're hosting the DNS service it's important to balance this with operational load (a lower value will mean more requests/minute coming in asking about data).  For you, since the DNS server is hosted elsewhere, it probably doesn't matter too much.  I'd put it at 3600 or so, which is 1 hour in seconds.

Comment: Thank you. I lack some basic understanding here. I already have an A-record for the IP to the webserver of the domain (domain.com) and now I should add an A-record for the mailserver to that domain (mail.domain.com). I do not understand how to keep both these records.
I get an error when I try to add an A-record for mail.domain.com (I try to enter both "mail.domain.com" and "mail"). Please see screen shot
http://img90.imageshack.us/img90/7753/addarec.jpg

Comment: I think I finally got it right, due to your help, This is what it should look like, isn't it?
http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/3213/subco.jpg